# React Date-Picker won't accept a Date

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, material-ui

I am trying to implement this date-picker in my application: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker

I've initialized the component like this:

```
        <Grid item xs={7}>
            <DatePicker
                name="Date"
                value={this.getDate}
                onChange={this.handleDateChange}
            />
        </Grid>
```

the value function returns the date and looks like this:

```
  getDate = () => {
    const dateToday = Service.todaysDate //service returns a string so we convert
      return new Date(dateToday)
}
```

but I get this typescript error which doesn't make any sense!!

```
Type '() => Date' is not assignable to type 'Date | Date[] | undefined'.   Type '() => Date' is missing the following properties from type 'Date[]': pop,
```

I am new to react and I am having trouble figuring this whole this out. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind values with actual js variables not function.
Moreover events should be bound to lambda expression.
So in your render() function you should add

```
let date = this.getDate();
return  (<Grid item xs={7}>
        <DatePicker
            name="Date"
            value={date}
            onChange={(event) => this.handleDateChange(event)}
        />
    </Grid>);
```